# Give some indication that review parameters have been tweaked

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

Whenever the review parameters are tweaked to include more posts, questions like these are bound to be asked:

- [Why does the late-answer review queue sometimes spike in size by over 5000?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150080/why-does-the-late-answer-review-queue-sometimes-spike-in-size-by-over-5000)
- [Why have 8k+ late answers just appeared?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152003/why-have-8k-late-answers-just-appeared?lq=1)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152036/review-late-answers-in-so-jumped-from-0-to-4-8k?lq=1
- [Stack Overflow late answers jump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152679/so-late-answers-jump)

I don't blame them, because if you haven't read Emmett's answer, it's not immediately obvious why the queues have suddenly skyrocketed in size.

Shouldn't there be some indication that the parameters have been tweaked? At least for the time being, I think it would be better to explain what's going on.

Comment: Aren't these parameters bound to stabilise sometime in the near future, making this request too localised?

Comment: @JQAn I believe so, but we'll cross that bridge when we get to it. For now, these questions keep popping up and I think it would be better just to explain what's going on.

Comment: +1 This particular question seems to get asked almost as frequently as **y u ban me?**

Comment: While I agree that it's not immediately obvious, I'm a bit confused why so many people are concerned to the point of asking about this in the first place. The whole "Got to get the queue down to 0 as fast as possible!" vibe I get from that last example is a bit concerning. I wonder if showing the total number of pending items for those lists is even beneficial, or if really it's just important to indicate which queues have any actionable items.

Comment: You're right in that it's generating too much confusion. We'll figure out a fix, which will likely involve growing the queue slowly and continually, rather than all at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll try not to drastically tweak "review parameters" in the future. The sudden spikes in queue size clearly generated too much confusion.

For the Late Answers queue in particular, we just deployed logic to *gradually* grow the queue, until eventually (~4 months from now) it includes every late answer ever.

Answer (score 3):

I think this can be addressed by making a meta post informing of the change, and then we can close new questions as dupes of the official one (perhaps made by a community manager)

We kind of did this when we had reputation changes I believe, and it worked.