# Why did the low quality posts review queue suddenly jump to 21k

Tags: support, review, low-quality-posts

(Eeeek!)

I was messing around with site settings, something I often do to relax in the evenings, when I happened to glance at the /review queues. I recoiled in shock, unwilling to believe my eyes - the usually empty Low Quality queue suddenly sported over **Twenty-One Thousand** new items!

What terrible catastrophe would cause such a sudden backlog?

Comment: I suddenly feel as though my head is no longer attached to my body.

Comment: @Shog9: You mean, you expect your developers to actually *use* the things they develop?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155471.

Comment: So...is this different from all the posts closed as duplicates of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150080/why-does-the-late-answer-review-queue-sometimes-spike-in-size-by-over-5000 (most recently http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155458/number-of-review-items)?

Answer (score 7):

We are slowly finding ways to classify posts that need extra review so you may see this queue go up on occasion.  Some of these posts may be ok and some of these may need a bit more attention.

We really appreciate any extra people who can help clear the backlog and help keep our quality high.

Comment: Note, 21k is rather small compared to the [massive cleanup effort](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83214/the-great-moderator-flag-turkey-shoot) from 2011. Well, perhaps not rather small, but definitely not huge.