# Is the `First Posts` queue full on SO?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, review

Since this morning, I haven't seen any new *first posts* to review in the First Posts queue (at least from about *2012-12-10 01:28:29Z*).

There have been some. One can tell because the number of reviews has been increasing during the day (~10 since this morning). I was also surprised to see that nobody has reached the threshold today (sad upvoter bots).

Has the [automatic fill been reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/150110/182741)? Or are only fresh first posts coming?

Comment: Now there are 536!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We found some indexes that were in need of adding.  They should start coming in now.

Comment: Way to take Stack Overflow offline adding your indexes, ya jerk

Comment: Meta SO comments: the new Instant Messenger.

Comment: The person responsible will be flogged ..  ahem..

Comment: There are less than 10 first posts for the last 4 hours, but lots of late answers to old questions (from people with only a single post). How is the index working out?

Comment: Great - check now.. and time to get to work :)