# logic behind review functionality

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review

Since I discovered the `review` functionality, once in a while I have a look in and try to give my contribution in doing `review task`s.

Generally, there are from 0 to max. 10 `First Posts`, which can be reviewed. However, as I had a look yesterday, there were **1.2k** new posts.

Now I was just wondering how this could happen. As I assume that at any time there are many users ready to do `review task`s, I don't think that suddenly 1.2k new users posted a question. Was there a kind of error in the queue (which I assume is existing), or some server issue, or am I not even allowed to ask/know this?

Comment: related: [Why does the late-answer review queue sometimes spike in size by over 5000?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150080/165773)

Answer (score 3):

There is a threshold for the maximum age of the posts. This threshold is increased once in a while resulting in a sudden increase in the review queue.

Comment: Doesn't that only apply to Late Answers?

Comment: @Asad no, see for example: [Why did the low quality posts review queue suddenly jump to 21k](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155493/165773)

Answer (score 0):

There was a small problem yesterday when no posts showed up for several hours. Then, suddenly...

See [Is the `First Posts` queue full on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158216/is-the-first-posts-queue-full-on-so)